# Place Range Slider into a DropDown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

How do I place a range slider into a dropdown? I assume there is a simple way to do this, but I'm not sure of the best way.

[image]

I want to hide the range slider into a dropdown like the others, and make it so that when I click a 'Date' button, the range slider pops down and you can use it.

Here's some sample code. I'm not tied to having it in tables like this. Please keep in mind that this range slider filters a datatables object. I'm working with some bootstrap, jQuery, ion range slider, and a custom css.

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="select">
        <select id="categorySelector" class="form-select selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-size="8"
            name="country" data-dropdown>
            <option value="">&#xf3c5;&nbsp;&nbsp;Category (All)</option>
            <option value="Option 1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <table id="myRangeSlider" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="js-input-from" id="min" name="min" value="0">
                </td>
                <td style="width:100%;"><input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" /></td>
                <td>
                    <p class="js-input-to" id="max" name="max" value="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Some libraries**

```
<!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- For Bootstrap Select -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <!--Range Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you want to put the dropdown into a dropdown, you just use the following code together with bootstrap.

```html
<div id="rangeDropdown" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    &#xf133;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date
                </button>
  <ul id="myRangeSlider" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <p class="js-input-from" id="min" class="minSlider" name="min" value="0">
      <p style="width:100%;"><input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="">
        <p class="js-input-to" id="max" class="maxSlider" name="max" value="0">
  </ul>
</div>
```